# for autocomplete in jquery it doesn't show the list

Tags: node.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: appUrl + '/somepath/tags',
    success: function (data) {                  
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            entireTags.push(data[i]);
        }
        $("#search").autocomplete({source: entireTags});     
    }
});
```

`data` looks like this:

```
["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4", ..., "tagN"]
```

After entering text, it doesn't automatically show the matched `list.itshows` when pressing <kbd>Down</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place console.log after the for loop and check whats the values you are getting in 
the array "entireTags"

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        entireTags.push(data[i]);
    }
  console.log(entireTags);
```

Comment: the data outputs as :     ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4", ..., "tagN"]

Comment: David Czihak-  the data outputs as : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4", ..., "tagN"]